# Scheduling issues with Control-M

Tags: scheduling, control-m

I am working on scheduling some jobs using Control-M. My scenario is as below:

I have the following jobs - `Job 1, Job 2, Job 3 and Job 4`. All of them does an insert into the same table. I have to schedule all the four jobs to start at the same time. Since they are inserting into the same table, I am running into lock issues.

I cannot add a dependency between these jobs because I will be adding more jobs to this stream. Also, there are no logical dependencies between these jobs.

Also, all these jobs call the same script, but with different parameters.

Is there any way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the "Resources" properties for the tasks. If they all need the same exclusive or limited to 1 in quantity resource then they will get run one at a time.

Comment: Thanks Brian..but unfortunately, I don't have any resources for these jobs.

Comment: Create a resource. Add it to each task.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Control Resource, no Quantitative Resources.
Only write in the field Control Resources the name of the used table with the option of Exclusive active. This parameter should be add on every Job that can make lock on that table. **You can keep the Exclusive un-selected for those Jobs that can use the table but don't lock it.**
Control Resource and Quantitative Resources are not the same.